# Is it possible to integrate Redmine into another website?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

I have an application I'm designing for a client and one of the features they requested was the ability to track tickets. I'm currently using Redmine and redirecting people to my instance so they can add tickets, issues, etc., however I'd like to integrate it into the actual website so I don't have to redirect users. Ideally, it would be a tab or sidebar that users could expand, add their ticket information, and then collapse.

I've seen a variety of questions about integrating other sites into Redmine, but is it possible to do it the other way around? Is there a way to do this or will I have to build my own system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the easiest way to do this is by building your own form and using the [Redmine API](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api)